# selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: the requested resource could not be found, or a request

Tags: selenium, exception, configuration, teardown, appium-java

getting exception
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
"org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource"

`enter code here`

```
public class BaseClass {
//read config file and initiate variables
ReadConfig readConfig = new ReadConfig();
public String username = readConfig.getUserName();
//public String password = "asas";
public String password = readConfig.getPassword();


public static AppiumDriver driver;
public static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger;


@BeforeClass
public void setUp ()
{
    
    try {
        
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(BaseClass.class);
    
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "bd178829");
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "D:\\automation\\CRMNextMobileAutomation\\src\\test\\resources\\apps\\CRMNextNative 6.29.0-release_screenshot_enabled.apk");
    dc.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2");
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.crmnextmobile.crmnextofflineplay");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.crmnextmobile.crmnextofflineplay.qr.QrScannerActivity");
    dc.setCapability("enforceAppInsall", true);

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    
    driver = new AppiumDriver(url,dc);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    
    System.out.println("CRMNext automation start..");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    
    //Clicking on Allow option on open permission pop up
    //driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
    
    if(!driver.findElements(By.id ("com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button")).isEmpty()){
        //THEN CLICK ON THE SUBMIT BUTTON
        System.out.println("permission_allow_button is found on page");
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
    }else{
        //DO SOMETHING ELSE AS SUBMIT BUTTON IS NOT THERE
        System.out.println("permission_allow_button not found on page");
    }
    
    //Clicking on Allow button of run in background pop up
    //driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
    if(!driver.findElements(By.id ("android:id/button1")).isEmpty()){
        //THEN CLICK ON THE SUBMIT BUTTON
        System.out.println("button1 is found on page");
        driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
    }else{
        //DO SOMETHING ELSE AS SUBMIT BUTTON IS NOT THERE
        System.out.println("button1 not found on page");
    }
    
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    System.out.println("CRMNext automation Before Skip..");
    //Clicking on Skip button
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.crmnextmobile.crmnextofflineplay:id/skip")).click();
    
    System.out.println("CRMNext automation after Skip..");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.crmnextmobile.crmnextofflineplay:id/relative_layout_continue")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    
    
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Cause is :"+exp.getCause());
        System.out.println("Message is :"+exp.getMessage());
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Test
public void sample() {
    System.out.println("Sample run");
}


@AfterClass
public void tearDown()
{

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    
}
```

//org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

all tests are failing due to this.

Answer (score 3):

**driver.close()**

The driver.close() command is used to close the current browser window having focus. In case there is only one browser open then calling driver.close() quits the whole browser session.

**Usability**

Use driver.close() when dealing with multiple browser tabs or windows e.g. when clicking on a link that opens another tab. In this case after performing required action in the new tab, to close the tab, call the driver.close() method.

**driver.quit()**

The driver.quit() is used to quit the whole browser session along with all the associated browser windows, tabs and pop-ups.

**Usability**

Use driver.quit() when no longer want to interact with the driver object along with any associated window, tab or pop-up. Generally, it is the last statements of the automation scripts. Call driver.quit() in the @AfterClass method to close it at the end of the whole suite.

```
Use following code in @AfterClass

@AfterClass
public void tearDown()
{

   if (driver != null)
      driver.Quit();
    
}
```